# Factorial Proof by Induction Question: $ \frac1{2!} + \frac2{3!} + \dots+ \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac1{(n+1)!} $?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction, factorial

$\text{Use the PMI to prove the following for all natural numbers n.}$

> $ \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} $

So for this question I get stuck because I cannot seem to make the left side and right side be equivalent.

$\color{Green}{Proof} :$

$\mathbf (I) \; Basis \; Step :$  Show $p(1).$ For $n=1$

$\frac{1}{(1+1)!} = 1- \frac{1}{(1+1)!} \Rightarrow \frac12 = \frac12$

$\mathbf (II) \; Inductive \; Step : $

Assume $p(k)$ for a PAC $k \in ℕ ,\; \; \;\; n=k$

$ \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} +\cdot\cdot\cdot + \frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(k+1)!} \; \;  \text{Induction Hypothesis}$

**Left Hand Side :** We need to show : $p(k+1)$ i.e. $n = k+1$

$\frac{k}{(k+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+1+1)!} \Rightarrow \ $

$\frac{(k+1)}{(k+1+1)!} +1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} $

**Right Hand Side**: $ n =k+1$

$\left(  1- \frac{1}{(k+1+1)!}\right) = 1- \frac{1}{(k+2)!}$

This is where I have made my mistake because I think I have made an arithmetic mistake on the left side because I cannot get them to be verifiable. Any hints on how to correct the  error would be appreciated. Have a good one.

Comment: How did you get that left-hand side for the $k+1$ case?

Comment: I edited my question I forgot that - $\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$

Comment: The left hand I kept trying to reduce to no avail, I could not get the right hand.

Comment: Read Brian's answer, your actual left-hand side is not right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the inductive hypothesis, we know that \begin{align*} \frac{1}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{k}{(k+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} &= 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} \\ &= 1 - \frac{k+2}{(k+2)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} \\ &= 1 - \frac{1}{(k+2)!}.\end{align*} Hence, if the statement is true for $n=k$, then it true for $n = k+1$, so by induction, it is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I just do not understand the 2nd line. How did you get $\frac{(n+2)}{(n+2)!}$?

Comment: You multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ by $n+2$. The numerator becomes $n+2$, and the denominator becomes $(n+2)(n+1)! = (n+2)!$.

Comment: I think I am starting to see what you are talking about the $n+1$ goes away because $(n+2)!= (n+2)(n+1)!.$  That is clever.

Comment: There is just one question I do not get? Is there a reason that you use n instead of k for your answer?

Comment: There's no reason. If it'd make you happier, you could swap every $k$ and $n$ in the above answer, and it'd still be valid. For exposition's sake however, it's best if you're consistent with your $k$s and $n$s the whole way through your argument. I've edited my answer so it's in line with your notation.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to show in the induction step is that

$$\frac1{2!}+\frac2{3!}+\ldots+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=1-\frac1{(k+2)!}\;.$$

Since your induction hypothesis is that the sum of the first $k$ terms on the left is $1-\frac1{(k+1)!}$, this amounts to showing that

$$1-\frac1{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=1-\frac1{(k+2)!}\;.$$

If you multiply $\frac1{(k+1)!}$ by $1$ in the carefully chosen form $\frac{k+2}{k+2}$, you should have little difficulty showing this.

Answer (score 1):

Although this post does not address the specific issue posed in the OP, I thought it might be instructive to present an alternative way forward.  To that end, we note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}
\end{align}$$

Now, the sum becomes a telescoping sum and we have immediately

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

as was to be shown!