# Polynomial ,divides and Induction Proof?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

> $\text{The polynomial } x-y \;\text{divides the polynomial}\; x^2-y^2 \text{ and } x^3-y^3 \text{because}\; x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y) \text{ and } x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2.) \; \text{for every natural number n       } \quad x-y \;\text{ divides  }\; x^n-y^n \text{ prove by induction.}$

What I am confused about in this example is when one makes $n=k$. Which variable is made equal to k.Where is $n$. Is it fair to assume that what the actual problem wants you to infer this. $x^n +y^n = x^n+y^n$

**(i) Basis Step:**  $x^n-y^n = x^n-y^n$

$x-y = x-y$

$0=0$

**(ii) Inductive step :**  $x^k-y^k = x^k-y^k$

WNTS: RHS: $n =k+1$

$x^{k+1} + y^{k+1}$

LHS: $x^{k+1} + y^{k+1} +x^k-y^k $

Is this a fair assumption to make I feel as if their is something fundamentally missing from my logic. Any suggestions would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say ${ x }^{ n }-{ y }^{ n }$ is dividing by $x-y$ then we have $${ x }^{ n }-{ y }^{ n }=\left( x-y \right) P\left( x \right) $$,where $P(x)$ is some polynomial.Now we should prove that ${ x }^{ n+1 }-{ y }^{ n+1 }$ is also dividing by $x-y$ 
$${ x }^{ n+1 }-{ y }^{ n+1 }={ x }^{ n+1 }-{ x }^{ n }y+{ x }^{ n }y-{ y }^{ n+1 }=\\{ x }^{ n }\left( x-y \right) +y\underbrace { \left( { x }^{ n }-{ y }^{ n } \right)  }_{ \left( x-y \right) P\left( x \right)  } ={ x }^{ n }\left( x-y \right) +y\left( x-y \right) P\left( x \right) =\\ =\left( x-y \right) \left( { x }^{ n }+yP\left( x \right)  \right)  $$ 
so it means

> $${ x }^{ n+1 }-{ y }^{ n+1 }=\left( x-y \right) \left( { x }^{ n }+yP\left( x \right)  \right) $$

Comment: Would this be proving the right hand side. Then would it be fair to assume left hand side is $x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}+x-y$ ?

Comment: Then they would equal for all n natural numbers?

Comment: @LittleJon,i don't know what do you mean,but it is a proof that you are looking for

Comment: That might be asking to much. I think I have enough information to make a good proof.

Comment: I always thought you had to make things equal but I guess there are exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

For the inductive step, suppose $x-y$ divides $x^n-y^n$ for some $n$. You have to prove that, under this hypothesis, $x-y$ divides $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}$.

**Hint:**

Rewrite it as $$x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=x(x^n-y^n)+xy^n - y^{n+1}$$
and make partial factorisations.

*Some details:*

By the induction hypothesis, $x^n-y^n=(x-y)q(x,y)$, so 
$$x(x^n-y^n)+xy^n - y^{n+1}=(x-y)q(x,y)+ (x-y)y^n=(x-y)\bigl(q(x,y)+y^n\bigr).$$

Actually, the induction step defines a recurrence relation for the quotient of $x^n-y^n$ by $x-y$, which allows to  prove the complete factorisation formula.

Comment: The one thing I still do not get is what is the left side and what is the right?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You know when one usually gets one of these problems it always defines what one equation is equal to but for this one I just cannot seem to grasp what the question is trying to tell me.  Like this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851511/factorial-proof-by-induction-question This one though is rather abstract.

Comment: I guess the l.h.s. here would be $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}$ and the r.h.s. its factorisation by $x-y$.

Comment: $x^n-y^n = (x-y)a$? This might be the original problem that it is asking. If so I think there would be no a. I dunno.

Comment: If $x-y|x^n-y^n$

Comment: @Little Jon: I've added some details for the inductive step.